# Can't get Unity Physics2D.BoxCast(NonAlloc) to register hits where RayCast works

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity (2019.2) I'm trying to use a boxcast on a beam weapon of width > 0. Using a raycast for this beam test works correctly, but the BoxCast returns zero results.

I'm not using any depth, distance, or layermask filters.

```
 colCountRay = Physics2D.RaycastNonAlloc(e.pos, Vector2.up, collsRay);
```

...correctly returns the hit objects, populating collsRay and setting colCountRay to the number of hit objects. But replacing that rayCast with this...

```
 colCountRay = Physics2D.BoxCastNonAlloc(e.pos, Vector2.right, 0, Vector2.up, collsRay);
```

...colCountRay is zero

I'm using this script to visualise the box cast and it's overlapping correctly...

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1156087/how-can-you-visualize-a-boxcast-boxcheck-etc.html

I've used boxcast before in another game so I'm completely stumped here! All the tested objects have 2D colliders and a kinematic RigidBody2D. Physics2D layer filters are enabled in Settings for collisions between all objects, although that shouldn't affect the boxCast results.

Comment: You are casting a box with height 0? Could you try to use a non-zero sized box for the casting, and see if that works?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. One of those simple errors I was too close to. Reply as an answer and I'll upvote you. ;)

Comment: Glad I could help, hope it becomes a good game. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are casting a box with height 0? Could you try to use a non-zero sized box for the casting, and see if that works?

Comment: Cheers. Conceptually there's no need for a height if you are casting a width through a scene to generate a bounding volume, but clearly the internal execution needs a height on the box. I've found 0.001f is the minimum height to register hits in my case.